# Removing Characters For an INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle

I am just putting together two tables on a table1.id should match with table2.rrn. The only issue now is that from one specific merchant they have decided to add additional characters in the RRN. Example being rrn = 'CA-878199056' when the vast majority of them would be '878199056'.

Is there anyway to tell oracle to ignore the 'CA-' part and treat rrn like the majority of them, that being, without the letters at the start. Here is my syntax

```sql
    SELECT
t1.RAN

FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
      ON t1.id = t.2.rrn
WHERE t2.ran IN (
'85130060227032902133394'
,'85130060230032062215242'
,'85130060234033308113213'
,'85130060239034609522107'
,'85130060245034968247553'
,'85130080248035168327488'
,'85130080250035224894674'
,'85130080250035226664661'
,'85130060258036741451588'
,'85130060264037041839581'
,'85130081074110038783421'
,'85130081074110038780955'
,'85130081075110108072647'

);
```

When this is ran I get the error message  "ORA-01722- Invalid Number" and I now know it has to do with an implicit conversation (thank you alex poole). ID is data type number and rrn is data type VARCHAR.

Comment: Try [REPLACE](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php), so the WHERE clause would be `WHERE REPLACE(t2.ran, 'CA-') IN (`

Comment: Thank you so much I have actually gone with the answer below but yours also helped me as well :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, that would be

```
WHERE substr(t2.ran, 4)               --> so that it skips "CA-"
IN ('85130060227032902133394' ...)
```

Comment: Thank you so much man! You have been great (again) hahaha.